# How to get last published date from a CmsResource in OpenCms

Tags: java, opencms

I'm unable to get the last published date of a resource. There is no way to do that with OpenCms API.
http://files.opencms.org/javadoc/core/org/opencms/file/CmsResource.html

That's very weird, it has to be stored in some place because OpenCms Workplace shows this information in the History option.

[image: History of a resource in OpenCms Workplace]

The method getDateReleased() from CmsResource class always returns DATE_RELEASED_DEFAULT until you set the availability of the resource.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I achieve this by digging in the source code from OpenCms.
I found the solution here, in the getListItems method:

https://github.com/alkacon/opencms-core/blob/branch_8_5_x/src/org/opencms/workplace/commons/CmsHistoryList.java

So I built this method to get the last published date from any resource:

```
public static Date getLastPublishedDate(CmsJspActionElement cms, CmsResource resource) throws Exception {
    CmsObject cmso = cms.getCmsObject();
    String sitePath = cmso.getSitePath(resource);

    if (cmso.readAllAvailableVersions(sitePath).size() > 0) {
        I_CmsHistoryResource histRes = cmso.readAllAvailableVersions(sitePath).get(0);
        int publishTag = histRes.getPublishTag();
        CmsHistoryProject project = cmso.readHistoryProject(publishTag);            
        return new Date(project.getPublishingDate());                                   
    } else {
        return null;
    }   
}
```

If NULL is returned then the resource has not been published yet.